# Is Visa required to Transit via Abu Dhabhi for transit more than 8 hrs. I do not intend to go out of the terminal

Tags: visas, transit-visas, uae

I am an Indian Citizen travelling from Washington DC to Mumbai via **Abu Dhabi** in July 2017.

There is a **transit** time of **8 hrs and 5 min** in Abu Dhabi and my next connecting flight is on the same terminal (3).

I will be **staying inside the terminal** and will not be going out into UAE. 
My luggage will also be checked-in through upto Mumbai.

When called Etihad, I am getting conflicting answers from the agents.

The etihad website here http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/more-than-4-hours.aspx does not give details whether it applies to travellers Not going out of airport.

Can someone please help me understand if I need a UAE Visa during this Transit if I don't intend to go out the terminal.

Please help.

Many thanks in advance.

---

***Answering my own question***:

I travelled in July and NO VISA was needed.
I stayed inside the terminal for more than 8 hrs.
You just need to follow the directions for 'transfers'.

DO NOT rely on Etihad agents as some of the agents told me that I needed a Visa if my stay is more than 8 hrs.

---

Comment: Added answer based on my real-time experience few weeks back!